# Office Scripts- How to delete last row

Tags: office-scripts

I am trying to delete the last row in my Excel Online document using Office Scripts.

I do not know what I am doing wrong, it is not deleting, does anyone have an idea?

My code:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    //getting the used range in the worksheet
    let usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();
    //getting the row count of the used range
    let lastRow = usedRange.getRowCount();
    //getting the row count of the range
    let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();
    usedRange.getCell(lastRow, 0).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a little more foolproof ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let usedRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();  
  let lastRowAddress = usedRange.getLastCell().getAddress();
  selectedSheet.getRange(lastRowAddress).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
}
```

Comment: You are a saint, thank you soo much! Works like a charm